# Add multiple filters to cardboard app rally

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, rally

I have one cardboard application which display's number of cards for each PortfolioItem/Feature. likewise it's on Rally platform `Release Planning`. I want to implement filter box like that.

Attached the screenshot of filters, which I want to implement.

[image]

Comment: what's wrong in the question? Why someone will hit -1 vote without commenting also, If you can't understand question or anything wrong ask for explanation.

Comment: I guess you earned a downvote because you didn't post any code, just a screenshot how it should look like. Sort of; 'please give me the code' which is not how stackoverflow works. You should first try is yourself and post the fragments where you stuck.

Comment: @sra - thanks for the reply, but i didn't need the code. I wrote the code to implement each filter with the help of comboboxes, but this is a combined customized functionality, so I need the idea how to go with it. How can I implement this specific thing. And it will be good if someone specify what's wrong in the comment rather than just to downvote the question.

Comment: Well *...but this is a combined customized functionality, so I need the idea how to go with it...* is still vague for a question. You may go much more in detail where exactly your problem(s) lies, to get a answer here. And yes, **downvoting without any comment is useless**.

Comment: @sra - again thanks, I will post my code too to be more specific with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sometimes get hints/code for your apps via the open source repo for the [Rally App Catalog](https://github.com/RallySoftware/app-catalog). For your example, there is available source code for the [Release Planning App](https://github.com/RallySoftware/app-catalog/blob/master/src/apps/releaseplanning/ReleasePlanningApp.js). Reviewing the source code, you can see that the Filter Picker is defined by the following requirement defined in the source:

`Rally.ui.gridboard.plugin.GridBoardCustomFilterControl`

And this is incorporated into the board by adding its plugin to the board configuration.

It's tempting to add this to a Simple Grid example, exactly as the Release planning board does, which I tried doing as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rally Example: Simple Board</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc3/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {
                Ext.define('Rally.example.SimpleBoard', {
                    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                    requires: [
                        'Rally.ui.gridboard.plugin.GridBoardCustomFilterControl'
                    ],

                    launch: function() {
                        this.add({
                            xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                            types: ['User Story'],
                            attribute: 'ScheduleState',
                            context: this.getContext(),
                            readOnly: true,
                            cardConfig: {
                                showIconsAndHighlightBorder: false,
                                editable: false
                            },
                            plugins: [
                                {
                                    ptype: 'rallygridboardcustomfiltercontrol',
                                    filterChildren: false,
                                    filterControlConfig: {
                                        margin: '3 9 3 30',
                                        blackListFields: ['PortfolioItemType', 'Release'],
                                        whiteListFields: [this._milestonesAreEnabled() ? 'Milestones' : ''],
                                        modelNames: ['HierarchicalRequirement']                                           
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                    }
                });

            Rally.launchApp('Rally.example.SimpleBoard', {
                name:"Rally Example: Simple Board",
                parentRepos:""
            });

        });
    </script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
  /* Add app styles here */
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if you try to load the app in this way, you'll get a 404 when it looks for the `Rally.ui.gridboard.plugin.GridBoardCustomFilterControl` class.

Looking at the [AppSDK2.0rc3 docs](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/), this plugin does not appear to be available under the Rally.ui.cardboard.plugins.* tree that's bundled into the SDK. See screenshot here:

AppSDK2.0rc3 screenshot excerpt:

[image: AppSDK2.0rc3 screenshot excerpt]

Nor does it appear that the Rally.ui.gridboard.plugin.* tree is bundled into the AppSDK. It is likely that the class *is* however, available to the Rally UI via a different javascript bundle (non-public) that the Rally developers use.

Perhaps it would be feasible for Rally Engineering to bundle this plugin into the AppSDK so that customer developers could use it - perhaps file a Feature Request on Rally Ideas or something like that to see if this is achievable.

Comment: thanks a tone mate..I was abel to make cardboard with portfolioitem/feature as cards. But want to give different filters,  I will try this and see if it works for me..